# How to set the default theme value while creating new user in Vtiger CRM?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

In Vtiger 6.4 while creating new user (xyz.com/index.php?module=Users&parent=Settings&view=Edit) there is a dropdown to select theme. It is defaulted to the "softed". 
I want to change it to my custom theme. I tried to search the View file for this but could not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value set at database level so can you please use below sql query 
UPDATE `vtiger_field` SET `defaultvalue` = 'Nature' WHERE `vtiger_field`.`columnname` = 'theme';